# save a cell array in matlab as .xlsx or .csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, xlsx, cell-array

I have a cell array *myFile* 637x16. The first row of the cell array is made of strings, because they will be the columns' labels in the .xlsx/.csv file.

From the second row on, the cell array is made of some columns with strings, and some columns with numbers.
I would like to export this cell array as a .xlsx or .csv file.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
'subject'   'PeakA' 'PeakL' 'number'    'epoch' 'code'  'type'  'latency'   'nitem' 'condition' 'ia'    'cover' 'variety'   'init_index'    'init_time' 'urevent'
5           3.50    82      13          1       201011  'pre'   2502        201     1           1       'y'     'h'         13              13.92        13
5          -1.27    112     55          2       61011   'pre'   8213        61      1           1       'y'     'h'         55              53.90        55
5           6.59    99      85          3       124011  'pre'   13924       124     1           1       'y'     'h'         85              82.45        85
5           12.65   105     127         4       178011  'pre'   19635       178     1           1       'y'     'h'         127             122.43       127
5          -0.35    105     157         5       89011   'pre'   25346       89      1           1       'y'     'h'         157             150.98       157
5           10.29   93      163         6       132011  'pre'   31057       132     1           1       'y'     'h'         163             156.69       163
5           4.61    65      193         7       166011  'pre'   36768       166     1           1       'y'     'h'         193             185.25       193
5           1.45    51      199         8       212011  'pre'   42479       212     1           1       'y'     'h'         199             190.96       199
```

I tried:

```
xlswrite('filename.xlsx', myFile);
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Warning: Could not start Excel server for export.
XLSWRITE will attempt to write file in CSV format. 
> In xlswrite (line 174) 
Error using xlswrite (line 187)
An error occurred on data export in CSV format.

Caused by:
Error using dlmwrite (line 112)
The input cell array cannot be converted to a matrix.
```

Comment: use `fprintf` instead. `fprintf(fid,'%s,%f\n',data{k,:});` loop your data with `k` iterator in a `for-loop`.

Comment: Not an answer, but consider using the [table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) data type instead of a cell array for this

Comment: @Dan if I run myTable = cell2table(myFile); it returns the following warning message for more than 100 times:
 `Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to character. > In matlab.internal.table.container2vars (line 57)`
`In cell2table (line 34) Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to character.`

Comment: Read [ask] and add a [mcve].

Comment: It is a warning, what results do you get? Which lines/columns/char are truncated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a sufficiently recent version of Matlab (R2013b or older), `writetable` is your friend.

```
%# create a table
tbl = cell2table(yourCellArray(2:end,:),'variableNames',yourCellArray(1,:));

%# write to file
writetable(tbl,'filename.xlsx')
```

If you want to use `xlswrite`, it may be worth converting all data to string first, or to write the variable names separately, before you write the rest - I believe Matlab checks data types on the first row, which can cause typecast errors.